# Convert http headers (string) to a python dictionary

Tags: python, http, header

Is there a standard function that will convert http headers into a python dictionary, and one to convert back?

They would need to support header folding, of course.

Comment: Where are you getting the http headers from?

Comment: from a file object (made from a socket)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than build your own using sockets etc I would use [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) Thus would get the data from the http server and parse the headers into a dictionary
 e.g.

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.python.org")
conn.request("GET", "/index.html")
r1 = conn.getresponse()

dict = r1.getheaders()
print(dict)
```

gives

> [('content-length', '16788'), ('accept-ranges', 'bytes'), ('server', 'Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g mod_wsgi/2.5 Python/2.5.2'), ('last-modified', 'Mon, 15 Feb 2010 07:30:46 GMT'), ('etag', '"105800d-4194-47f9e9871d580"'), ('date', 'Mon, 15 Feb 2010 21:34:18 GMT'), ('content-type', 'text/html')]

and methods for put to send a dictionary as part of a request.

Comment: *They would need to support header folding* httplib does not handle folding correctly. See https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/3

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost I don't think that is clear the RFC says that - it says It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one  "field-name: field-value" pair .... which httplib does

Comment: That's only half of the truth :) The second half is in the preceding sentence *Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present in a message **if and only if** the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)].* httplib folds all headers with the same name regardless of the above condition. See [addheader](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Lib/httplib.py#l220) method in `httplib.py`.

Comment: Relevant Python issue - [continuing problem with httplib multiple set-cookie headers](http://bugs.python.org/issue1660009)

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost - I see the issue now - it seems some servers/browsers don't stick to the RFC :( so in some cases you will need to do something else - ass the python issue for a workaround -although this does not seem to be a high priority issue

Answer (score 4):

In case you don't find any library solving the problem, here's a naive, untested solution:

```
def fold(header):
  line = "%s: %s" % (header[0], header[1])
  if len(line) < 998: 
    return line
  else: #fold
    lines = [line]
    while len(lines[-1]) > 998:
      split_this = lines[-1]
      #find last space in longest chunk admissible
      split_here = split_this[:998].rfind(" ")
      del lines[-1]
      lines = lines + [split_this[:split_here]),
                       split_this[split_here:])] #this may still be too long
                                                 #hence the while on lines[-1]
    return "\n".join(lines)

def dict2header(data):
  return "\n".join((fold(header) for header in data.items()))

def header2dict(data):
  data = data.replace("\n ", " ").splitlines()
  headers = {}
  for line in data:
    split_here = line.find(":")
    headers[line[:split_here]] = line[split_here:]
  return headers
```

Comment: I would be surprised if this actually worked in all cases. :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this, and fix what errors I find if I can't get anything else.

Comment: I've turned this answer into community wiki, so you can merge the fixes as/if required.

Answer (score 2):

### The best way to achieve this is using a HTTP request converter like this one:

You can copy a request as CURL and then this converter will translate it to a Python request

https://curl.trillworks.com/

BTW if you don't trust the link you can search in Google for "curl converter" and it will probably show in the first results.
https://github.com/NickCarneiro/curlconverter

[image]

### How to copy a request as CURL

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed

Comment: @Mattwmaster58 you are welcome, this tool is just amazing

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, but [this](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/node562.html) seems to be along the lines of what you are looking for

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I realize this post is from 2010, but I thought it best to speak up. I agree with [Mark's Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268724/convert-http-headers-string-to-a-python-dictionary/2272948#2272948) up until the dict is assigned.

Since `getheaders` returns a list of tuples and the [dict constructor](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) builds dictionaries from key-value pairs stored as tuples you can create what you want directly:

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.python.org")
conn.request("GET", "/index.html")
response = conn.getresponse()

headers = dict(response.getheaders())
print(headers)
```

Now you get:

> {'content-length': '18891', 'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'server': 'Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)', 'last-modified': 'Mon, 30 May 2011 19:50:25 GMT', 'etag': '"105800d-49cb-4a48399368240"', 'date': 'Mon, 30 May 2011 21:29:32 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html'}

If you want those tuples back, call `headers.items()`.

Answer (score 1):

### My beautiful and simple solution:

```py
headers = '''GET /api/v1/friendships/1506146503/followers/?count=12&max_id=QVFDdVNEamtCWTBCYUhvbjI3RHhNeGU2NlVnM3c4RERMTmNHZ184dm0wMUNmS0J0SnBoOThRQlFWdWs1eUpBcWJGYk1xb3dnSVUzc2R3M2JrQlRpVWJEQQ%3D%3D&search_surface=follow_list_page HTTP/1.1
Host: i.instagram.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Origin: https://www.instagram.com
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://www.instagram.com/'''


def get_headers_as_dict(headers: str) -> dict:
    dic = {}
    for line in headers.split("\n"):
        if line.startswith(("GET", "POST")):
            continue
        point_index = line.find(":")
        dic[line[:point_index].strip()] = line[point_index+1:].strip()
    return dic


get_headers_as_dict(headers)

# Result:
{'Host': 'i.instagram.com',
 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0',
 'Accept': '*/*',
 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
 'Origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com/'}
```

Answer (score 0):

And this is my version without for iteration:

```
import re
req_line = re.compile(r'(?P<method>GET|POST)\s+(?P<resource>.+?)\s+(?P<version>HTTP/1.1)')
field_line = re.compile(r'\s*(?P<key>.+\S)\s*:\s+(?P<value>.+\S)\s*')

def parse(http_post):
    first_line_end = http_post.find('\n')
    headers_end = http_post.find('\n\n')
    request = req_line.match(
        http_post[:first_line_end]
    ).groupdict()
    headers = dict(
        field_line.findall(
            http_post[first_line_end:headers_end]
        )
    )
    body = http_post[headers_end + 2:]
    return request, headers, body
```